# Remembering triggers in jQuery

Tags: jquery, triggers

[jQuery][1] always remembers your mouse triggers, either clicks or hovers. So if you mouse-enter and mouse-exit four times, it will execute that event four times.

How do I make it "forget" the triggers, so that when I mouse-enter and -exit the trigger it only executes it once?

**EDIT:**
How would I do that in this code?

```
$("#products").mouseenter (function () {
    $(".slider").animate({"margin-top":"0px"},750);
    $("#p_dropdown").animate({"height":"96px","margin-top":"45px"}, 750);
    $(".products_dropdown").animate({"height":"32px"},750);
      });
$("#p_dropdown").mouseleave( function() {
    $(".slider").delay(750).queue(function(n){$(this).animate({"margin-top":"46px"},1150)});
    $("#p_dropdown").animate({"height":"0"}, 750);
    $(".products_dropdown").animate({"height":"0px"},750);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)'s function *[one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)* does exactly what you are looking for. Any event you hook up, will be executed only once.

For example,

```
$("#div1").one("click", function() {
    alert("Will be shown only once");
});
```

Comment: @Peter Mortensen
Thanks for the answer!

How would that work in this code?
Check my question edit.

Comment: `$("#products").one("mouseenter", function(){...})` may be? @ChrisHolstein

Comment: I found out that this is not exactly what I'm looking for,